# Let $G$ be a finite group with cardinality not divisible by $3$. How can one show that for every $g \in G$ there is an $h \in G$ such that $g=h^3$?

Tags: finite-groups

Let $G$ be a **finite group** whose cardinality is not divisible by $3$. How can one  show that for every $g$ belonging to $G$ there exists an $h \in G$ such that $g=h^3$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative strategy is to choose $g \in G$, and note that $|\langle g \rangle|$ divides $|G|$ by Lagrange's theorem, so that the order of $g$, say $n$, is not divisible by $3$. Then there are integers $a,b$ with $na+3b = 1.$Then we have $g = g^{1} = g^{na+3b} = g^{na}g^{3b} = 1_{G}g^{3b} = (g^{b})^{3}$.

Answer (score 4):

For every $g$, the map $h  \mapsto h^3$ on $\langle g \rangle$ is injective (otherwise there'd be an element of order $3$, contradicting the assumption), whence this map is surjective and the claim follows.

Comment: Why would it have an element of order three ($G$ is not abelian)?

Comment: Right. I changed the argument a bit.

Comment: @quid : actually, your original intention can be fixed, but the argument is not much different from other ones: choose integers $x,y$ with $3x + |G|y = 1$. If $g,h \in G$ with $g^{3} = h^{3}$, then we also clearly have $g^{|G|} = h^{|G|}$,so that $g = g^{3x + |G|y} = (g^{3})^{x}(g^{|G|})^{y} = (h^{3})^{x}(h^{|G|})^{y} = h^{3x + |G|y } = h$.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson I would not have though of doing it that way; thanks for the information.