# Finite group. Let $G$ a finite group without order elements $3$ such as $(ab)^3=a^3b^3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ a finite group without order elements $3$. Suppose

$$(ab)^3=a^3b^3$$

for all $a,b \in G$

Let $a \in G$. Demonstrate that there is $x \in G$ such as $x^3=a$

My attempt:

Since the group has no elements of order $3$, then

$$x^3=e \Longrightarrow x=e$$

Let $a,b \in G$ such as $a^3=b^3$

$$a^3=b^3 \Rightarrow a^3b^{-3}=e \Rightarrow (ab^{-1})^3=e$$

Therefore $ab^{-1}=e \Rightarrow a=b$

This means that no two cubes of different elements are equal. So if we cube all $n$ elements in the group we get $n$ different results. Hence every element of the group must be a cube.

Let $a \in G$, every element of the group must be a cube, then for $x \in G$

$$x^3=a$$

Is my attempt correct?

Other attempt:

Let $a \in G$ and $m=\text{ord}(a)$ Since the group has no elements of order $3$, then $m$ is not divisible by $3$, thus $\text{gdc}(m,3)=1$ by Bezout's Theorem exist $s,p \in \mathbb{Z}$ such as $ms+3p=1$,

$$a=a^1=a^{ms+3p}=a^{ms}a^{3p}=(a^m)^s(a^p)^3=e^s(a^p)^3=(a^p)^3$$

If $x=a^p$ then $x^3=a$, $x \in G$ because $a^p \in G$

Is my other attempt correct?

Comment: Yes, it is OK. Of course, it is just [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1608300/let-g-be-a-finite-group-with-cardinality-not-divisible-by-3-how-can-one-sho). There you can find it also reformulated: the map $h  \mapsto h^3$ is surjective.

Comment: How did you go from $a^3b^{-3}=e$ to $(ab^{-1})^3=e$?

Comment: By hypothesis $(ab)^3=a^3b^3$

Comment: Notice you want to say *such that*: "This is an element such that [something holds]". *Such as* is rather used to provide specific examples of something you're talking about, *such as* the example I provided above. :)

Comment: Did you mean “without elements of order $3?$” Because “… without order elements $3$” doesn’t make sense.